# Change Permissions Nginx create files

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, permissions

I am using this proyect, installation via docker: https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo

It creates several containers, one of them is NGINX.

NGINX is running with user 1001.

Images are stored in media/finding_images and I have set permissions to media for user 1001:

`chown 1001:1001 -R media`

When I create an image, thus, the image is created with this permissions:

https://pasteboard.co/JODIv40.png

Also, when I upload an image, the server gives error 500, even though it is uploaded correctly.

https://pasteboard.co/JODIUtE.png

I would like:

1. By default creating images with permissions 644.
2. Know why I get error 500 in the Nginx and know what is happening.

Maybe it is not very straightforward to give an answer since it is a project and would be required to see what's going on ....

Comment: Look at setting umask

Comment: It is specially the error 500 that I have that drives me crazy